# SonarQube snapshot cleanup

Tags: sonarqube

we are running a Sonarqube 6.0 instance and have some questions about the snapshot cleanup. We are still using the default values like:

"Keep only one snapshot a month after - Default: 52"

But we still have more than one snapshot per month for e.g. May 2015:

Mai     26  13:58   9.11.0.0-1-SNAPSHOT
        12  19:58   9.10.0.0-3-SNAPSHOT
        12  13:58   9.10.0.0-2-SNAPSHOT

Does anyone knows how to get around this? We have no more space on the database ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These analyses are not deleted in order to keep at least one analysis per version (9.10.0.0-2-SNAPSHOT, 9.10.0.0-3-SNAPSHOT, ...).

Dropping them won't save significant space. Depending on database, exporting and re-importing data can help (I mainly think about mysql here). If postgresql is being used, you should check that vacuum is correctly scheduled. Refreshing indices can also be an option.